# onclick() not working on first click for HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

So I made a 5x5 grid using HTML's `<table>` element. I want each cell to turn red when it is clicked and revert back to white when it isn't. It looks like it won't detect the first ever click on each cell. Once the first click has been triggered, it alternates from red and white normally under 1 click, but when you click it for the very first time for that instance, it does not respond. Why is it that a cell responds on the first click after it has been clicked on twice, but doesn't respond on the first click if it has never been touched before?

HTML snippet:

```
<div class="board">
<table type="board">
 <tr>
        <td id="r1-c1" onclick="changeColor('r1-c1')"></td>
        <td id="r1-c2" onclick="changeColor('r1-c2')"></td>
        <td id="r1-c3" onclick="changeColor('r1-c3')"></td>
        <td id="r1-c4" onclick="changeColor('r1-c4')"></td>
        <td id="r1-c5" onclick="changeColor('r1-c5')"></td>
</tr>
...
</table>
</div>
<button id="submit" onclick="submitted()">Generate</button>
```

The snippet is nested inside body and 2 div tags respectively.

CSS snippet:

```
table[type=board],tr,td{
    background-color: white;
    min-width: 80px;
    min-height: 380px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

JS code:

```
function changeColor(id)
{
    if(document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor == "white"){
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "red";  
    }else{
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot help you unless we see how the event is getting triggered.

Comment: I think the first time element.style.backgroundColor is not set so `document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor == "white"` is false as `document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor === undefined`, it enters the else and sets the background to "white". you could workaround this by either checking if is undefined and setting it to red or switching the condition (if (red) white; else red;) .

Comment: Check whether r u applying css in initial load. If it not, u have check for undefined property also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code. It will work.

```
function changeColor(id){
    if( (document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor == "white") || (document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor == "")){
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "red";  
    }else{
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This very simple solution fixed the problem. Thank you for recognizing it in the limited amount of code that I provided. But I wonder, why is the background color during the very first click undefined but not after that first click on that cell?

Comment: U have not set background-color initially in css. If u have not set the specific  property, calling through javascript gives u NULL value.

Comment: Hmm...I did set the `background-color` property in CSS as white, but I still got the error.

Comment: My question is why does clicking it the second time give it background color white but not during the first click?

Comment: can u put ur code in fiddle? So that anyone can able see it

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided the HTML, So I have to create the DOM.

```
document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor
```

Do you mean to say each of the cell has an id?

Which may be too complex for large grid. Instead you should use `rowIndex` & `cellIndex` to locate a particular cell.

Also you can use `event` object and find the `target`. Saying that it mean `event.target` will help you to locate the cell which is clicked

```
var getTable = document.getElementById("demoTable");
//Declare a variable to hold the cellIndex & rowIndex
// On next click check if this values,& if not null change the background color of that cell
var col = "";  
var row = "";
getTable.addEventListener('click',function(event){
  console.log(col,row)
  if(col !== "" && row !== "" ){
    document.getElementById('demoTable').rows[row].cells[col].style.backgroundColor ="transparent" ;
  }
    col = event.target.cellIndex;
    row = event.target.parentNode.rowIndex;



//Set background of the cell on which it is clicked

    document.getElementById('demoTable').rows[row].cells[col].style.backgroundColor ="red" ;  
    })
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/m8f2nL0q/)